# Django not hitting Class View on Form Get

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have this url defined:

```
url(r'^persons/(?P<id_person>P\.\d+)/forms/(?P<id_form>\w+\.\d+)/$', views.PersonFormView.as_view())
```

The regex checks out testing with a regex testor: `persons/P.1/forms/D.1/`

This is my Class View:

```
class PersonFormView(APIView):
def get(self, request, id_person, id_form, format=None):
    form = Form.get_form_for_person(self, id_person, id_form)
    serializer = FormSerializer(form, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

GET it is not hitting the View.  Help is very much appreciated.

UPDATE:
It appears URL definitions are colliding.  I have these two:

```
url(r'^persons/(?P<id_person>P\.\d+)/forms/(?P<formacronym>\w+)/$', views.PersonFormCreateView.as_view()),
url(r'^persons/(?P<id_person>P\.\d+)/forms/(?P<id_form>\w+\.\d+)/$', views.PersonFormView.as_view()),
```

I'd like to be able to hit the APIs using these urls:

```
/persons/P.1/forms/D/
/persons/P.1/forms/D.1/
```

Is it possible to define 2 URLs, so I am able to browse using the 2 example urls provided just above?

Comment: What is it hitting then? Do you get an error?

Comment: I am getting a 404:  GET /persons/P.1/forms/D.1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 23

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is not correct for that url.

Try this one instead:

```
url(r'^persons/P.(?P<id_person>\d+)/forms/D.(?P<id_form>\d+)/$', some_view),
```

**Edit:**

if second argument is optional it should be declared with an *. Like this (not tested):

```
url(r'^persons/P.(?P<id_person>\d+)/forms/D[.](?P<id_form>\d*)/$', some_view),
```

I really don't see the point of adding points and D or P chars. I recomend to keep it simple, for expample:

/persons/1/forms
/persons/1/forms/1

Wich would be acomplished by two regex:

```
url(r'^persons/(?P<id_person>\d+)/forms/$', some_view),
url(r'^persons/(?P<id_person>\d+)/forms/(?P<id_form>\d+)/$', some_view),
```

plus, in the view, id_form argunment must have a default value.

Comment: Are you getting an exception? I would 1. check full url. 2. check that APIView is defined, as you are extending that class (you have to import it:  from rest_framework.views import APIView).

Comment: @Dowling - please note I updated my question.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: 2nd parameter is not optional.  I would like "/persons/P.1/forms/D/" to hit one api and "/persons/P.1/forms/D.1/" to hit a different api.  So when it is just a letter hit one api and when it is a letter + dot + number hit a different api.